# Trying to access folders in a sharedrive

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to access folders in a sharedrive but the numbers placed in front of the folder names are causing issues. I have no idea why the numbers in front of the two folders 02_COLLECTION_VEHICLES and 07_GIS_LAYERS are present. I created the GIS_LAYERS folder but I didn't name it along with the 07_. At any rate, my program can access the sharedrive folders just fine that do not have the numbers and underscores in their name. So what can I do to access these folders? I was thinking of using regular expressions but im not sure how to use them in this case.

Here is the code for accessing and retrieving the file:

```
def readerOut():
    import os
    import re
    os.chdir(\
    ('S:\PAVE_MANAGEMENT\AUTOMATED_DISTRESS_SURVEYS\02_COLLECTION_VEHICLES\07_GIS_LAYERS')
    reader = open('2015_FILES_COMBINED.CSV')
    yield reader
```

When I run this code I get a WindowsError: [Error 3] and it says that it cannot find that specified file path.

Would something like this work if it was in the function?:

```
re.search('^[0-9]\\d*_COLLECTION_VEHICLES\^[0-9]\d*_GIS_LAYERS')
```

Comment: why don't you map the drive and give a try ?

Comment: I am mapped to the drive on the computer I use the drive several times a day for GIS and databases.

Comment: yeah. You have already mapped. Kind of misunderstood the question

Comment: Several other folders in those sharedrives also have the numbers with underscores in front of their names and its really a problem for me right now.

Comment: instead of using one back slash , you need to use multiple slashes. Can u try that and let me know ?

Comment: Yes that worked! After I placed the fourth slash a drop down menu came up and I chose the folders I wanted. That was very helpful thank you! You can copy and paste this and use it as an answer if you want:  os.chdir('S:\PAVE_MANAGEMENT\AUTOMATED_DISTRESS_SURVEYS\\\\02_COLLECTION_VEHICLES\\\\07_GIS_LAYERS')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiple back slashes instead of single back slash and then give a try

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to this question. Using four slashes in front of each of the folders in question allows me to access those folders. Also, when I enter the fourth slash, a drop down menu in IDLE allows me a choose which folder I want to access. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/998217/thothadri-rajesh

```
os.chdir('S:\PAVE_MANAGEMENT\AUTOMATED_DISTRESS_SURVEYS\\\\02_COLLECTION_VEHICLES\\\\0‌​7_GIS_LAYERS')
```